# Mapping Application for Excel

Tags: gratis, maps, microsoft-excel

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I need to map around 20 truck routes that are listed in excel. I would like to plot each stop as a point on a city map, and then draw a line/route connecting those stops. I was thinking of using Google MyMaps but I am not sure that it is able to create that many routes efficiently.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you code, or are you looking for an off the shelf solution?

Comment: I can code but an off the shelf solution would be prefferable due to the comapnies download policies

Comment: I am thinking that this would be easy with Leaflet & Python (I would export the Excel to CSV & manipulate that, but see also https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) Hope you fin an OTS solution. Good luck